# I would like to display in a loop a div class one time in two (Symfony)

Tags: loops, symfony, if-statement, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a personal project and I want to do this:

[image]

So there is my code with a loop which works well:

```
  {% for uneInfo in lesInfos %}
        <div class="row featurette ">
            <div class="col-md-7 {% if (loop.first or loop.last) %} order-md-0 {% else %} order-md-2 {% endif %}">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading"> {{ uneInfo.title }} </h2>
                <p class="lead">{{ uneInfo.description }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 {% if (loop.first or loop.last) %} order-md-0 {% else %} order-md-1 {% endif %} ">
                <img class="featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto"
                     alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">
    {% endfor %}
```

On my page it look like this:

[image]

How can I alternate the display in my loop? I work with Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) operator with two as modulus to decide if you're in an even or uneven loop index.

```
{# if loop.index % 2 == 0 #}
```

0 % 2 = 0
 1 % 2 = 1
 2 % 2 = 0
 3 % 2 = 1
 4 % 2 = 0
 5 % 2 = 1
 etc...

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why.

Answer (score 0):

another opportunity

```
  {% for i in 1..10 if i is not odd %}
      {{ i }},
  {% endfor %}
```

or

```
  {% for i in range(low=2, high=10, step=2) %}
    {{ i }},
  {% endfor %}
```

or

```
  {% for i in 1..10  %}
    {% if loop.index is not odd %}
      {{ i }},
    {%  endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```